# Adding a dynamic logo to Genesis primary nav

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I would like to add a logo ( get_custom_logo() ) in the Genesis navigation bar but when it's blank, there's to be text. I've achieved this in a similar fashion for the header but cannot for the primary nav. The end result DOES work but when the user goes to the "customize" part of "site identity" the change is not visible, until you hit "publish" then refresh the actual page.

I need the change to be seen in "customize" mode as the logo is being changed. Here's the code the semi-functions...

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'prefix_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add Menu Item to end of menu
 */
function prefix_add_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        if (( has_custom_logo())) {
            $thelogo = get_custom_logo();
            $items .=  '<li class="menu-item">' . $thelogo . '</li>';
        } else {
            $items .=  '<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Theme Name</a></li>';
            return $items;
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to apply this method throughout the site for other hooks. If anyone can point to what I'm doing wrong, that would help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It won't refresh in preview unless you add a custom setting to $wp_customize for your image or you add a new PHP class for the site logo. Either way, it's not an easy fix.